# Regex code finds no match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a ur link from a data item using below regex function but getting error "match not found'.

Content: `<a href="https:// ... ">`

Regex Function:

```
export function GetImage2(content) {
    myRegexp = new RegExp(/<a.*?href="(.*?)"/);
    match = myRegexp.exec(content);

    if (match) {
        // match[1] = match[1].split(/\s+/);
        // match[1] = match[1].join(" \' ");
        // console.log('Matches found:' + ' ' + match[1]);
        return match[1];
    }
    console.log('No match found');    
}
```

I am at wits end on this. Thanks as you assist.

Comment: Could you add better examples of what your input is/can be and what you expect to match?

Comment: This can use some cleanup, but does work as intended. Most probably, your input is not what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Note that by default `.` will not include newlines. If your anchor tag has attributes on new lines, this regex will not find a match. If you need to include newlines in your match, consider using `[\s\S]*?` as an alternative.

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - use a parser, but try `<a\b[^>]* href="[^"]*"`

Comment: This is the data item I am trying to get just the https:// ... link from this content: 
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112571000091010561964/photos">Hotel Fusion</a>"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can using this regex to select link from a tag

```
/([^"]*)">/g
```

Your code:

```
export function GetImage2(content) {
    myRegexp = new RegExp(/([^"]*)">/g);
    match = myRegexp.exec(content);

    return match ? match : 0;    
}
```

Comment: getting match of 0 rettunned (ie no match). Trying to extract the https:// tag from "<a href=".https://..."> data item

Comment: The suggested regex works. But I now found out that my content is being returned as "undefined" and hence no match when calling the function to extract from it. Thx